# Jquery function is not working for TextArea

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

On my asp.net web application I am restricting the user input characters using a 
**JQuery function**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input').on('input', function () {
            var c = this.selectionStart,
                r = /[^a-z0-9@&%./() +-]/gi,
                v = $(this).val();
            if (r.test(v)) {
                $(this).val(v.replace(r, ''));
                c--;
            }
            this.setSelectionRange(c, c);
        });
    });
```

Functions works on textbox as expected but its not working on multiline textbox.
 [design eg:`<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddAdds" class="form-control" placeholder="Default Input" autocomplete="off" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox`]
Why this function have no effect on multiline textbox.??
 Somebuddy please help me..

Comment: Because in HTML it is not an `input`, but a `textarea`. Your selector does not work then.

Comment: Asp.Net classical html tag when  rendered.Can you look to on chrome this TextBox

Answer (score 1):

Your function is only targeting `inputs`, you need to target `textareas` too :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input, textarea').on('input', function () {
        var c = this.selectionStart,
            r = /[^a-z0-9@&%./() +-]/gi,
            v = $(this).val();
        if (r.test(v)) {
            $(this).val(v.replace(r, ''));
            c--;
        }
        this.setSelectionRange(c, c);
    });
});
```